# How to upcast webform submission in custom routes resp. controller?

Tags: 8, routes, webforms

Using this route:

```
confirm:
  path: '/node/{node}/submission/{webform_submission}/confirm'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MymoduleController::confirm'
    _title: 'Confirm your submission'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'confirm webform submission'
```

And visiting `node/15/submission/15/confirm` I get the error:

> RuntimeException: Controller
>   "Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MymoduleController::confirm()" requires
>   that you provide a value for the "$submission" argument. Either the
>   argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default
>   value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument
>   after this one. in
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver->getArguments()

What am I doing wrong? Why doesnt it load the submission 15? It does exist.

Edit: this is my Controller, the second argument is always null:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Controller\EntityViewController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmission;

/**
 * @todo
 */
// class MymoduleController extends ControllerBase { // doesnt make a difference
class MymoduleController extends EntityViewController {
  public function confirm(EntityInterface $node = null, EntityInterface $submission = null) {

    debug($submission);

    $response = new Response( 'test' );

    return $response;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need to declare the parameter type:

```
confirm:
  path: '/node/{node}/submission/{webform_submission}/confirm'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MymoduleController::confirm'
    _title: 'Confirm your submission'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'confirm webform submission'
  options:
    parameters:
      webform_submission:
        type: entity:webform_submission
```

The parameter names also need to match, so update your controller accordingly:

```
public function confirm(EntityInterface $node = null, EntityInterface $webform_submission = null) {
```

Comment: doesnt work unfortunately, the 2nd parameter is always NULL. if i look in how webform handles it itself (`WebformSubmissionViewController::view`) i wonder if this is even possible. should be though, since its a regular entity, isnt it?

Comment: ive updated my code.

Comment: You should also set the type hint the entity type interface.
 confirm(NodeInterface $node = NULL, WebformSubmissionInterface $submission = NULL)

Comment: @jrockowitz i had like that initially, but it doesnt work either. i switched to entityinterface bc thats how webform does it itself. thanks though

Comment: Symfony is sensitive to the parameter name @Alex - make sure it’s the same in the routing file and the controller.

Comment: @Clive such a stupid mistake. thanks so much, it was the parameter name :)